# Why do I get a ClassNotFoundException for GAE app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have a GAE app I deployed i January using Objectify, and haven't looked at since. When I deploy the app today, and access the app, I get the following exception:
    com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyLogger warn: Could not         instantiate listener dk.louise.dao.InitializerContextListener     (JettyLogger.java:29)
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dk.louise.dao.InitializerContextListener

where dk.louise.dao.InitializerContextListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener, and is defined in web.xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" id="WebApp_ID"     version="3.0">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            dk.louise.dao.InitializerContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
...
```

It seems many others had a similar issue and fixed it by using the most recent GAE SDK. I use 1.9.73, but this does not fix the problem.

Thanks,
Louise

Answer (score 1):

`ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundError` almost always indicate something is wrong with your classpath setup. It won't be a GAE-specific issue, it's a Java issue.

It's hard to debug this from the information provided - how are you running the app? Maven, gradle, from your IDE? Look into how your classpath is set up and make sure the code is present that you expect to be present.